# How to overwrap on geom_bar in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I would like to create a bar chart with ggplot in R.
The sample data is as follows:

```
Name <- c('Sample1', 'Sample2', 'Sample3')
Total <- c(86020045,30974095,1520609)
Part <- c(41348957, 2956650, 595121)
DT <- data.frame(Name,Total,Part)
DT
ggplot(DT, aes(Name, Total, fill=Name)) + 
        geom_bar(position="stack",stat="identity")
```

What I would like to show is the **stack bar chart** that shows each Name's Total counts, and show the Part counts within the bar + label the % of it on in the middle of the bar.

Is there any way possible to do this? I've been searching on here but haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: You'll need to reshape: `library(tidyverse) ; DT %>% mutate(Not_Part = Total - Part) %>% select(-Total) %>% gather(part, value, Part, Not_Part) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Name, y = value, fill = part)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')` and then use `geom_text` to label

Comment: @Alistaire Thanks a lot! this works beautifully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh... It seems like someone already commented the answer while I was writing it down. I'll post mine anyways since it's slightly different.

```
DT <- transform(DT, Part0 = Total - Part)

library(reshape2)
DT2 <- melt(DT, id.vars = c("Name", "Total"))
DT2 <- transform(DT2, perc = value/Total * 100)

ggplot(DT2, aes(Name, perc, fill=variable)) + 
    geom_bar(position="stack",stat="identity") +
    geom_text(data = subset(DT2, variable == "Part"), aes(y = (perc),
        label = paste0("Total = ", Total, "\n",
                       "Part = ", value, "\n", 
                       round(perc, 1), "%\n")))
```

If you use `value` instead of `perc` you will get a proportional bar chart but since the total for sample 3 is a lot smaller than sample 1, it's going to be difficult to read the table. So I decided to use percentage instead of the actual values.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Indeed, this is good way to visualize to figure the ratio at sight.